# How to import variables and style rules into one file

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have `theme.scss` file which contains the style of my website and it's content looks similar to this

```
//Direction variable[rtl|ltr]
$direction: ltr;
//Theme style
.selector-1 {
    color: red;
}
.selector-2 {
    color: red;
    @if $direction == ltr {
        right: 9px;
    } @else {
        left: 9px;
    }
}
```

I need to separate the `$direction` variable from the style. I need to create 2 new files; `ltr.scss` & `rtl.scss`. If the locale is ltr then I'll call `ltr.scss` from my angular component, else I'll call `rtl.scss`.

What I did so far:

`theme.scss`

```
.selector-1 {
    color: red;
}
.selector-2 {
    color: red;
    @if $direction == ltr {
        right: 9px;
    } @else {
        left: 9px;
    }
}
```

`ltr.scss`

```
$direction: ltr;
@import './theme.scss';
```

`rtl.scss`

```
$direction: rtl;
@import './theme.scss';
```

But I'm getting `SassError: Undefined variable.` for `$direction`.

I understand that I should import either `ltr.scss` or `rtl.scss` in `theme.scss` file to remove the error, but In this case I'll have to create another two new files `theme-ltr.scss` & `theme-rtl.scss`; each of them has redundant code.

How can I create only two new files which I'll include in my angular component (one for ltr and the other for rtl), and make each one of them declare the direction variable & import the website theme file?

Comment: How do you load rtl and ltr css files? Is it at run time? And what do the rules apply to? One specific components? All components?

Comment: are you sure you included theme.scss in two files you mentioned. ?  (and not imported theme.scss at any other place) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you replace the **@import** with @use you can use the **with** keyword to pass a variables through a configuration to the imported file. It would look like this:

```
@use './theme.scss' with (
  $direction: ltr
);
```

For more information about **@use** and **with** you can take a look at the official SASS documentation: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#configuration